# Can't figure out WFS URL filter - what amI doing wrong?

Tags: wfs, filter, getfeature

I'm trying to figure out how to use the filtering function on a WFS layer. Any where I look, there is not an example of the XML AND the query alongside it explaining how it works. In the URL query below, my filter is completely ignored. (This is just an example, I have tried several modifications to this URL, to no avail.)

Can someone provide an example of a working URL query with the filter parameter?

```
http://maps.co.pueblo.co.us/outside/services/pueblo_county_roads_wms_only/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typename=pueblo_county_roads_wms_only:Roads&maxfeatures=2&filter=%3CPropertyIsLike%3E%3CPropertyName%3EOBJECTID%3C/PropertyName%3E%3CLiteral%3E66580%3C/Literal%3E%3C/PropertyIsLike%3E&
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps its your XML Filter code? Try wrapping your current filter in

```
<ogc:Filter></ogc:Filter>
```

like

```
<ogc:Filter>
  <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyName>OBJECTID</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>66580</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
```

[That works.](http://maps.co.pueblo.co.us/outside/services/pueblo_county_roads_wms_only/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typename=pueblo_county_roads_wms_only:Roads&maxfeatures=2&filter=%3Cogc:Filter%3E%3Cogc:PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3Cogc:PropertyName%3EOBJECTID%3C/ogc:PropertyName%3E%3Cogc:Literal%3E66580%3C/ogc:Literal%3E%3C/ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3C/ogc:Filter%3E)

It is strange that the examples in [mapserver's docs](http://mapserver.org/ogc/filter_encoding.html) work, when the seemingly same syntax doesn't work on yours.

```
http://maps.co.pueblo.co.us/outside/services/pueblo_county_roads_wms_only/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typename=pueblo_county_roads_wms_only:Roads&maxfeatures=&filter=<ogc:Filter><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>OBJECTID</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>66580</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:Filter>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have spent hours digging through sparse documentation trying to find this.

Comment: All the MapServer filter examples are wrapped inside <Filter> element but the original filter used in the question started directly from <PropertyIsLike>. Your target WFS takes it as invalid and skips the filter. However, GeoServer seems to be lenient and accepts also `http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&FILTER=%3CPropertyIsLike%20escapeChar%3D%22!%22%20wildCard%3D%22*%22%20singleChar%3D%22%23%22%3E%0A%3CPropertyName%3ESTATE_NAME%3C%2FPropertyName%3E%0A%3CLiteral%3EI*%3C%2FLiteral%3E%0A%3C%2FPropertyIsLike%3E`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&PROPERTY_NAME=STATE_NAME&FILTER=%3CFilter%20xmlns:gml=%22http://www.opengis.net/gml%22%3E%3CIntersects%3E%3CPropertyName%3Ethe_geom%3C/PropertyName%3E%3Cgml:Point%20srsName=%224326%22%3E%3Cgml:coordinates%3E-74.817265,40.5296504%3C/gml:coordinates%3E%3C/gml:Point%3E%3C/Intersects%3E%3C/Filter%3E

MapServer documentation shows examples about the filters http://mapserver.org/ogc/filter_encoding.html. Examples are not extremely good because they lack the namespace stuff and url-encoding. MapServer does not care about namespaces because it does not do schema validation but many other WFS server brands do.

**EDIT**

Filter and links to demo service at Boundless for making PropertyIsLike queries. Notice the introduction of wildcard characters.

```
<Filter> <PropertyIsLike escapeChar="!" wildCard="*" singleChar="#"> <PropertyName>STATE_NAME</PropertyName> <Literal>Illinois</Literal> </PropertyIsLike> </Filter>
```

[Select STATE_NAME like 'Illinois'](http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&FILTER=%3CFilter%3E%0A%3CPropertyIsLike%20escapeChar%3D%22!%22%20wildCard%3D%22*%22%20singleChar%3D%22%23%22%3E%0A%3CPropertyName%3ESTATE_NAME%3C%2FPropertyName%3E%0A%3CLiteral%3EIllinois%3C%2FLiteral%3E%0A%3C%2FPropertyIsLike%3E%0A%3C%2FFilter%3E)

[Select with wildcard STATE_NAME like 'I*'](http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&FILTER=%3CFilter%3E%0A%3CPropertyIsLike%20escapeChar%3D%22!%22%20wildCard%3D%22*%22%20singleChar%3D%22%23%22%3E%0A%3CPropertyName%3ESTATE_NAME%3C%2FPropertyName%3E%0A%3CLiteral%3EI*%3C%2FLiteral%3E%0A%3C%2FPropertyIsLike%3E%0A%3C%2FFilter%3E)

Comment: Do you have an example where a string field is being queried instead of a geometry intersection? If you use the URL above, you'll see that my filter is completely ignored...I don't even get a "0 results" error or bad syntax error.